# C - modify stack base pointer address

Tags: c, linux, pointers, stack

I want to allocate on the heap a stack frame for each function call, but for that I need to modify the stack base pointer for each function.

Is there any way to get that pointer and modify it in C under Linux?

Comment: You might explain WHY you want to do this.

Comment: Can't you just use a custom structure to pass arguments/return values? Similar to what Lua does? http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_CFunction

Comment: The only way to do this is with assembler.

Comment: It is a bet with a teacher from college.How can i get the EBP from the current stack pointer and modify it's address to a memory zone allocated on heap?My knowledge of asm are very little.

Comment: @user1311596 depends on the system You might be able to do tricks like this with getcontext()/setcontext()

Answer (score 0):

The only (practical) way to manually modify ebp is inline assembly or just write a function in assembly. If you have an assembly function you could do something like this (I am not really experienced with x86 assembly fyi)

```
; void function(void* heapPtr)

function:
    push ebp
    mov  reg, esp
    mov  esp, [esp+4]
    mov  ebp, esp
    ...
    mov  esp, reg
    pop  ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the function `alloca()`. Its use is not recommended, but most compilers has an implementation for it.

Comment: alloca allocates from the stack, not from the heap

Comment: I found a gcc function void* __builtin_frame_address(unsigned int level) that returns the address of the function call that is on the level "level".0 for the current function,1 for the caller and so on.But it seems that i cannot assign another value to the pointer returned by the function.Can it be a security limitation from the compiler?

Comment: @ShinTakezou Yeah, sorry I misread the original question. My bad.